# Linear Algebra: describing all possible matrices $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2+2A-8I=0$.

Solve the equation in $A$, namely describe all possible matrices $A$.

---

So, I found the spectrum of $A$, namely $\{-4,2\}$, so do I describe all possible matrices by putting those eigenvalues on the diagonal of the matrix for all upper triangular combinations that are possible?

Comment: why upper triangular?

Comment: All similar matrices to that set of diagonal matrices.

Comment: "Describe all possible matrices $A$"  They are the set of $n\times n$ matrices whose only eigenvalues are $-4$ or $2$ (*possibly both, possibly only one of them*).  There is literally nothing else you can glean from that information alone.  They could be upper triangular, they could be lower triangular, they could be neither, they could be diagonalizable, they could be nondiagonalizable, $\dots$  You do at least know that $0$ is not an eigenvalue so you do know that it must be invertible.

Comment: I was thinking that because the diagonal values of an upper triangular matrix are the eigenvalues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have that $A^2+2A-8I=0$ we know that the polynomial $x^2+2x-8 \in I(A)$ where $I(A)$ is the ideal of the endomorphism we are considering. So this is clearly a multiple of the minimal polynomial of the matrix (which we know generates the ideal). If we decompose this polynomial we have $x^2+2x-8=(x+4)(x-2)$ from which we know the possible eigenvalues, or the spectrum: $sp(f)=\{-4,2\}$.

The minimal polynomial of this matrix so can be only $(x-4), (x-2)$ or $(x-4)(x-2)$.

By using the **Jordan Normal form** theorem, we can conclude that all the matrices which respect this identity are diagonal: they can have all twos, all fours or both.

Example of all the possible matrices:

$$
  D_1 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -4 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & -4
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
  D_2 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & -2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
  D_3 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -4 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & -4 && \\ &&& -2 && \\
    &&&& \ddots & \\ &&&&&-2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Hope you're satisfied!

Answer (score 0):

Since this polynomial has only simple roots and is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, $A$ can be written in [Jordan Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Minimal_polynomial) using blocks of size $1$: i.e. it is diagonalisable. Hence such matrices are precisely the diagonalisable ones with eigenvalues from $\{-4,2\}$.